# Find $P(X=r, Y=s)$ from $P(X\le r, Y \ge s)$.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

An urn contains balls numbered $1$ to $N$. Let $X$ be the largest number drawn in $n$ drawings when random sampling with replacement is used. Find the joint distribution of the largest and the smallest observation. (Hint: Calculate first $P(X \le r, Y \ge s)$.)

The hint indicates that $Y$ represents the smallest number drawn in $n$ drawings. I need to compute $P(X=r, Y=s)$. I first thought that $P(X=r, Y=s) = P(X\le r, Y\ge s)-P(X\le r-1, Y \ge s+1)$. However, the answer show that $P(X=r, Y=s) = P(X\le r, Y\ge s)-P(X\le r, Y\ge s+1) -P(X\le r-1, Y\ge s)+P(X\le r-1, Y \ge s+1)$.

I think that this is a pretty basic result, but I can't explain myself why the first is wrong, but the second is correct. Could you elaborate this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between the events $(X\leq r, Y \geq s)$ and $(X\leq r-1, Y \geq s+1)$ is only contained in  $(X=r)\cup (Y=s)$ but not in $(X=r) \cap (Y=s)$.

Consider the case $X=r$ and $Y=s+1$. Then we do have $X \leq r$ and $Y \geq s$. We do not have $X\leq r-1, Y \geq s+1$.  Hence $P(X\leq r, Y \geq s)-P(X\leq r-1, Y \geq s+1)$ includes the probability of $X=r,Y=s+1$ which we don't want.

Comment: Could you add a little bit more detail about your statement? I don't clearly understand why "the difference between the events ... is only contained in $(X=r) \cup (Y=s)$".

Comment: @shk910 I have added an expalnation . I hope it s clear now.